# Primer on MathJax

Tags: support

Since we have MathJax enabled, it might be a good idea to advertise that it is on and point to a primer on using.  Amateur radio is so full of math, it's an important tool. I know my way around the SE network but didn't have a need to use MathJax until becoming active here and it's not a terribly obvious markup.

If there is a way to note that MathJax is on during the ask a question phase, that would be great and if there is a one primer to rule them all, we should link to it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Created the question as Amber suggested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225131/primer-on-mathjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not, to my knowledge, a way to alter what appears at the Ask a Question stage - but if someone has a good primer, we could potentially feature an announcement post linking to it.

You could also ask on the general StackExchange meta for them to add a link to a guide on the Ask a Question page for SE sites which have MathJax enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to realize is that MathJax uses $\LaTeX$ markup. Knowing that, it's much easier to search for solutions. Just don't search for [latex primer](https://www.google.com/search?q=latex%20primer): that's something totally different.

[Mathematics.SE meta has a good primer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), though for them, "primer" means some of the more advanced features. There's also an entire SE site on the topic: [tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).